# Flutter Floating Search bar inside ListView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I need to have two floating inputs inside of a ListView.
I'm using this package: https://pub.dev/packages/material_floating_search_bar

My problem is that the floating bar's results don't get fully shown because it tries to show inside of the SizedBox the Bar is included in:

[image]

Is there a way to show it on fullscreen? Would it be a good idea to have use a stack and have the FloatingBar and the ListView as children???
Or can I somehow set a high z-index to the FloatingBar?